# Instance of class in Java can't be tested for null

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, getter

I'm trying to troubleshoot a null-pointer exception that keeps me from populating an array adapter.  I've traced it down to the point at which I create an instance of the class, and so to try to troubleshoot, I created the following toast:

```
private void showSplits() {
    // populate the split line
    Split s = new Split();
    s = mTransaction.getSplit();

    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    if (s != null) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), s.getCategory(), duration);
        Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), s.getDescription(), duration);
        Toast toast3 = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), s.getAmount(), duration);
        toast.show();
        toast2.show();
        toast3.show();
    } else {
        Toast toast4 = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "S was null.", duration);
        toast4.show();
    }
```

....
}

When run, the result of this method is to neatly print out the content of each field of the split, then neatly print out "S was null."   I've verified that I'm calling the method only once, so I can't see how s could both be null and not null.

Here's the detail of the class...

```
public class Split implements Serializable { 

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static final String JSON_CATEGORY = "category";
private static final String JSON_AMOUNT = "amount";
private static final String JSON_DESCRIPTION = "description";

private UUID mId;
private String mCategory;
private String mAmount;
private String mDescription;

public Split(String category, String amount, String description) {
     mCategory = category;
     mAmount = amount;
     mDescription = description;
}

public Split() {
    mId = UUID.randomUUID();
    mCategory = "none";
}

public Split(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
    if (json.has(JSON_CATEGORY)) {
           mCategory = json.getString(JSON_CATEGORY); 
    }
    if (json.has(JSON_AMOUNT)) {
        mAmount = json.getString(JSON_AMOUNT);
    }
    if (json.has(JSON_DESCRIPTION)) {
        mDescription = json.getString(JSON_DESCRIPTION);
    }
}

public JSONObject toJSON() throws JSONException {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
//    if (mCategory != null) {
        json.put(JSON_CATEGORY, mCategory);
//    }
//    if (mAmount != null) {
        json.put(JSON_AMOUNT, mAmount);
//    }
//    if (mDescription != null) {
        json.put(JSON_DESCRIPTION, mDescription);
//    }
    return json;
}

// Factory method to convert an array of JSON objects into a list of objects
// User.fromJson(jsonArray);
public static ArrayList<Split> fromJson(JSONArray jsonObjects) {
       ArrayList<Split> splits = new ArrayList<Split>();
       for (int i = 0; i < jsonObjects.length(); i++) {
           try {
              splits.add(new Split(jsonObjects.getJSONObject(i)));
           } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
      }
      return splits;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return mCategory;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    mCategory = category;
}

public String getAmount() {
    return mAmount;
}

public void setAmount(String amount) {
    mAmount = amount;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return mDescription;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    mDescription = description;
}
```

}

To the best of my abilities to tell, showSplits is called only once in the fragment I'm working in.

Comment: Is `s` an abbreviation for "Schrödinger's cat"???

Comment: First of all you assign a variable to `s` (which is a horrible name for a variable, but this isn't code review, so I digress), then the next line you change the content of `s`. Second, where is `mTransaction` being defined? Could it be null?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code, so it would appear that `showSplits` actually is getting called more than once.  How did you verify that it isn't?  Maybe add another toast at the beginning of `showSplits` to verify...

Comment: Hey, `s` is no worse a name than `toast2`, `toast3` and so on if you already know you've got `Toast`.  @ajb

Comment: @DavidWallace Sorry, I guess that was a bit obscure... I was referring to his question about whether `s` can be both null and not null at the same time.  It wasn't a comment on the variable name.

Comment: Oh, right, sorry @ajb.  I seem to be humour-impaired today.  I think maybe I skimmed through the comments far too quickly, and kind of merged yours and MeetTitan's in my stream of consciousness.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the first line you are referencing s variable to a new **Split Object**, And in the second line you are changing the reference of s to **mTransaction.getSplit()**. If the object is returned by **mTransaction.getSplit()** is null then your s will reference to null. Means value of s will be null.

```
Split s = new Split();
s = mTransaction.getSplit();
```

your **mTransaction.getSplit()** may be returning null value , Try to debug it

Comment: This does not answer the question.  If `getSplit()` returns null, then why is it showing `toast`, `toast2`, `toast3`?

Comment: can you show your fragment's code also that might help in solving problems.

Comment: I had definitely mis-ordered quite a bit of the assignments of the Split Object.  Fortunately no quantum conundrums here.